# How to pass parameters of XSLT transformation Schema in Tridion 2013 SP1 for XSLT TBB's

Tags: 2013, xslt-mediator

We have newly migrated to Tridion 2013 SP1 and as the xslt mediator extension is depricated and the new inbuilt xslt mediator is introduced in this version.

I wanted to know how we need to pass the parameters to the XSLT TBB inorder to set the values of "output type","package items name prefix" etc.

for input and output we are using

```
<?XsltMediator inputItemName="Output1" outPutItemName="Output2"?>
```

Also while converting the legacy XSLT's to the new XSLT's does the the parameter schema come into picture which was being used in earlier version XSLT Tbb's.

Thanks

Comment: The fact that Tridion now ship an XSLT mediator has no impact whatsoever on the formal status of the old XSLT mediator, as it was never a supported product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass parameters to an XSLT building block, you simply need to add the parameters to the package, [as described in the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#docid=concept_55A8DD7E35754A0FA425C56D5977AE94&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=XSLTTemplateCustomParams.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_55A8DD7E35754A0FA425C56D5977AE94&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=xslt&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1397916277604&currentQuery=xslt&currentScope=).

Quoting the example from that documentation page: if your XSLT expects a parameter `myParam` like this:

```
<xsl:param name="myParam">My Default Value</xsl:param>
```

... then you can set this value in an earlier template building block, like this:

```
package.PushItem("myParam", Item)
```